# Usage of python function comparison dunders

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datamodel

### Question

Python functions have comparison dunders (see print out below). But they are `NotImplemented`. Fair enough. But what is their intended use, and how does one go about using them? When I assign a callable to `func.__gt__`, I'm not seeing it be called when I do `func < other_func`.

### Example Code

I could see the use of having `(foo > bar)` being a function equivalent to `lambda x: foo(x) > bar(x)`, but equally (and arguably more useful), it could be used to construct a pipeline.

For example, we could have

```py
def composeable(func):
    func.__gt__ = lambda g: lambda x: g(f(x))
    func.__lt__ = lambda g: lambda x: f(g(x))
    return func
```

Which could be used as

```py
>>> def composeable(func):
...     func.__gt__ = lambda g: lambda x: g(f(x))
...     func.__lt__ = lambda g: lambda x: f(g(x))
...     return func
...
>>> @composeable
... def f(x):
...     return x + 2
...
>>> def g(x):
...     return x * 10
...
>>> h = f.__gt__(g)
>>> assert h(3) == 50  # (3 + 2) * 10
>>> h = f.__lt__(g)
>>> assert h(3) == 32  # (3 * 10) + 2
```

Yet, curiouser and curiouser, this doesn't work:

```py
>>> h = f > g
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'function'
```

### Notes: The callable `NotImplemented` function dunders.

```
__eq__: NotImplemented
__ge__: NotImplemented
__gt__: NotImplemented
__le__: NotImplemented
__lt__: NotImplemented
__ne__: NotImplemented
```

Code to generate the above print out:

```py
from inspect import signature

def f(x): ...

for aname in dir(f):
    attr = getattr(f, aname)
    if callable(attr):
        try:
            x = attr(*len(signature(attr).parameters) * [''])
            if x is NotImplemented:
                print(f"{aname}: NotImplemented")
        except Exception as e:
            pass
```

Comment: Dunder methods are looked up on the class, not the instance of the class.

Comment: True. Sill, how can one use them, and how *should* they be used. (I'd be a bit hesitant to change the FunctionType by doing `f.__class__.__lt__ = ...` (if even that's allowed!)).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't get what you are trying to obtain. How can > or < operator be used with functions. Like what does it mean to make a function > another function?

Comment: @Anwarvic He's trying to use `f < g` and `g > f` as to mean function composition: `(f < g)(x) == f(g(x))`

Comment: Also, note that `f > g > h` isn't going to work the way you want, since comparison operators are parsed specially before the underlying dunder methods ever get involved.

Comment: And `f.__class__.__lt__ = ...` is *not* allowed.

Comment: I agree with @Barmar partially, but more fully, what he is trying to do is understand how these can and/or should be used, or if they're just a vestigial feature (functions are objects and `object` has them). Composition was just an example.

Comment: And to @Anwarvic, I say... Like... `f < g` could mean anything you want really. A more intuitive choice (than composition) for `<` would probably be any transitive and [antisymmetric relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_relation). This may seem foreign and obscure to a "normal" developer, but would be quite common if you're developing mathematically inclined tools.

Comment: @chepner: Indeed. Further, `TypeError: type 'function' is not an acceptable base type`. So it seems the python gods indeed created a world with vestigial features that are just meant to tease a mathematician with functional pipe dreams.

Comment: In defense of Python, mathematical functions are just a tiny piece of what the `function` type covers.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing you can do is define a *wrapper* which supports composition. Due to the handling of comparison operators, I would recommend using `>>` and `<<` for composition.

```
# Assumption: the wrapped callable take a single argument
class ComposableCallable:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __lshift__(self, other):
        @ComposableCallable
        def _(x):
            return self.func(other.func(x))

        return _

    def __rshift__(self, other):
        @ComposableCallable
        def _(x):
            return other.func(self.func(x))

        return _

    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.func(x)


@ComposableCallable
def f(x):
    return x + 1

@ComposableCallable
def g(x):
    return 2 * x


assert (f << g)(3) == 7  # 2*3 + 1 == 7
assert (f >> g)(3) == 8  # (3 + 1) * 2 == 8
```

Comment: I +1 the code because it's an elegant solution to making an operator implement composition. But composition was just an example, not the question (in fact, the actual problem that brought me to this was different, but composition was easier to explain). The question is (1) what is their intended use (if any), and (2) how does one go about using them (given (put simply) dunders work with classes, and you can't subclass functions) . If I don't get any answers to my actual question after some time, I'll accept yours to reward the not-just-discarding-the-question effort.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. `__gt__` and `__lt__` so that you can customize how instances of new classes compare against each other. The issue here is simply the you can't modify an existing built-in class.

Comment: Not sure how to say it otherwise. Perhaps "how can/should one use the comparison dunders of a function, if at all possible". At this point it looks likely that the answer is _you can't use them, they are just disabled vestigial features of `object`_. Obviously, we can delegate to a function to be able to use these dunders, but it just seems strange to have to do this when the base class contains these already.

Answer (score 0):

> Yet, curiouser and curiouser, this doesn't work:

This has nothing to do with the implementation of the dunder methods, and everything to do with the fact that you're trying to modify the existing behaviour of the built-in function type. You won't be able to modify the underlying class, and assigning these attributes on instances is ignored.

> how can one use them, and how should they be used.

You use them for your own classes, where there is a natural comparison between instances. For example, the standard library `fractions.Fraction` class supports these comparisons; and being implemented in Python, needs to use these methods.

> it could be used to construct a pipeline.

Aaaaaaaaugh.

This is very much against the Zen of Python. There are reasons it doesn't already work that way. The things Numpy does with operators are already pushing it IMHO, and mostly tolerated because of how incredibly useful they are. (Also, as pointed out in the comments, Python's special handling of chained relational operators will make this not work the way you want it to for non-trivial cases.)

Comment: There's nothing particularly wrong with a pipeline. Function composition would be a *fantastic* feature, but the primary opposition to it is that Python functions are too general to support a single notion of composition.

Comment: My objection mainly is to spelling the composition operation that way.

Comment: Again, the point of my question was **not** about pipelines. It was just an example. But I am definitely amused by the Aaaaaaaugh reaction and the tendency of many pythonistas  to take it as law, instead of as a beautiful invitation to reflection. My reflection brings me to the conclusion that for **my** context, such dos and don'ts are more in the way of having code mirror thought as simply and elegantly as possible.